# how to delete a file or a photo from the folder when deleting it from database?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

hi i'm try to delete image from folder but i'm getting this error message

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\File' not found

when i `dd()` the image path it look like this : `"C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\public\/images/1544525527.jpg"`
here is my delete code:

```
 $post = Post::find($id);
$file= $post->image;
$destinationPath = public_path('/images');
$filename = $destinationPath.'/'.$file;
File::delete($filename);
```

and i upload image like this:

```
 if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
            $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
            $post->image = url('/public/images/').'/'.$name;
        }
```

Comment: it should be: `\File::delete($filename);` or add a `use` statement at the top of your controller.

Comment: `C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\public\/images/1544525527.jpg` why do you have some back slashes and some forward slashes in the file path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the class at the top of your controller file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two solutions for this, first you can import the class by add this code in controller file

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

or alternatively you can use the full path class in your code, so your code should be like this,

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$file= $post->image;
$destinationPath = public_path('/images');
$filename = $destinationPath.'/'.$file;

//fullpath class
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::delete($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

direct delete from your directory please try this will use in your controller

```
use File;
```

that also use in your controllers function

```
   $update = tablename::where('id',$request->input('uid'))->where('status',1)->first();
    if ($request->hasFile('cover'))
    {
         File::delete(public_path().$update->pu_cover_photo);
    }
```